# Display list elements in separate inputs

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to print a list of strings in my JSP. I have this in my controller:

```
List<String> profileNames = new Vector<String>();
...
modelMap.addAttribute("pn", profileNames);
```

and this in my JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${pn}" varStatus="rIndex">
    <input type="text" value="${pn}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

By doing this, each input box is getting populated by all elements of the list.

However I need each item of the list in a separate input box, something like `${pn.get(index)}`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good but you mistyped the value of the input.

Replace this:

```
<input type="text" value="${pn}" />
```

with this:

```
<input type="text" value="${p}" />
```